# How to bind input value from child component in Svelte?

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, svelte

## ideal

I'd like to get input data from child component.

## What I have tried

```
<script>
  import Input from "./Input.svelte";
  let userGoal = "";
</script>

<h1>Your Goal is {userGoal}</h1>

<Input {userGoal} />
```

```
<script>
  export let userGoal = "";

  $: console.log(userGoal);
</script>

<input type="text" bind:value={userGoal} />
```

`$: console.log(userGoal);` shows userGoal at each event which is as I expected. However, It doesn't affect to parent Component.

## Summary

I'm new to Svelte.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just change `<Input {userGoal}/>` to this:

```html
<Input bind:userGoal/>
```

[Demo here](https://svelte.dev/repl/c233f0db93fa4f3ba3f503fefd6faa7d?version=3.16.0). If you want to call it something else in the parent, do `bind:userGoal={somethingElse}`.

[Here's a tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/component-bindings) on component bindings.

Comment: Wow, great. Thank you very much. I have an another question, but why it's different way from "parent to child"? When trying pass input value to child, I didn't need to write `bind`.

Comment: Because normally data should flow from parents to children. Flowing from children to parents should be the exception, used sparingly.